# convert numpy array type: float32 to char

Tags: python, numpy

I need to convert a numpy array of type float32 into char in a way that each 4 consecutive members form a float number. so the resulting array should have a length 4 times the original.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [numpy.ndarray.tostring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html).

```
x = NP.arange(0, 10, dtype=float)
s = NP.ndarray.tostring(x)

print len(x)
print len(s)
print repr(s)
print NP.fromstring(s, dtype=float)
```

Output:

```
10
80
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 @\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"@'
[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
```

On my machine the float type is a 64 bit double, so the length of `x` is 10 and the length of `s` is 80.  If you plan to share the string with other machines keep [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in mind.